# How to solve $\frac{15!}{(x-1)!(16-x)!}=\frac{15!}{(2x+1)!(14-2x)!}$ for $x$?

Tags: combinatorics

I have to solve this problem.

$$\frac{15!}{(x-1)!(16-x)!}=\frac{15!}{(2x+1)!(14-2x)!}$$

I imagine that the answer somehow lies in the recursive definition of $n!$ which is $n(n-1)!$. But I can't guess how to use it to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\binom{15}{x-1}=\binom{15}{2x+1}$$

We know $\displaystyle\binom nr=\binom n{n-r}$

So, either $x-1=2x+1$ or $x-1=15-(2x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

$$C^{15}_{x-1}=C^{15}_{2x+1}$$
so either $x-1=2x+1$ or $(x-1)+(2x+1)=15$